# make shorter os.getenv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dry

```
import os

BUCKET = os.getenv("BUCKET")
IN_CSV = os.getenv("IN_CSV")
OUT_CSV = os.getenv("OUT_CSV")
```

now, you see the problem right? I don't want to retype the variable name twice, is there a way to not do it? maybe some function get_and_init_env.
get_and_init_env(BUCKET) after this is executed there should be a variable of name BUCKET with value os.getenv("BUCKET") in locals()

Comment: This doesn't seem very repetitive, but if you're on a crusade to make your code a little shorter for whatever reason, you could could use a comprehension and destructure it like...`bucket, in_csv, out_csv = [os.getenv(x) for x in ("BUCKET", "IN_CSV", "OUT_CSV")`

Comment: It's probably bad practice, but if you wanted to, you could have `def get_and_init_env(s): globals()[s] = os.getenv(s)` and then do `get_and_init_env("BUCKET")`.

Comment: What you're asking is to make your code far less clear for the sake of saving a few characters.  You *could* write a function that takes a string, gets its value from the environment, and stores it in `globals()[string]`.  But please don't.

Comment: Agree with a lot of what folks say. Fewer codes doesn't necessary make it better. Personally I like `pydantic` `BaseSettings` as you can define use os env or .env and load them easily. You have an explicit set of configuration for your library/app.

Answer (score 0):

May not be *exactly* what you need but to save time typing in things built on ipython, I once made a class that took in a dict of strings (such as one that can easily be made from `os.environ`), and in it's `__init__` it called `setattr` to make itself have attributes that reflected the dict contents.  From there I just had to `.blah` that instance instead of `['blah']` but more importantly in ipython could `.b<tab>` and bring up the items it could be.  Probably went something like

```
...
class DotDict:
    def __init__(self,dictish):
        self._original = dict(dictish) #a dict has a lot of useful capabilities that can be routed to it...
        for x,y in self._original.items():
            setattr(self,CleanStr(x),y)
   ...

...
#make useful dicts part of the module
env =DotDict(os.environ)

...

from MyMod import env as env0
env0.BUCKET #just use it...
```

Since most environ vars should be pretty clean, you can probably just use `x` instead of `CleanStr(x)` but should really have a way to make any x object into a valid name, be it str or repr or hash related and prefixed by some favorite character sequence.